# Create dictionary in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (2022,'A1', "cat", 'eng', 3, 56.768639), 
         (2022,'A1', "rabbit", 'eng', 10, 56.768639), 
         (2022, 'A2', "dog", 'eng', 10, 54.114841),
           (2022, 'A2', "mouse", 'eng', 20, 81.114841),
    ],
    ["data",'group', "word", 'lang', 'count', 'value']  # add your column names here
)
df.show()
+----+-----+------+----+-----+---------+
|data|group|  word|lang|count|    value|
+----+-----+------+----+-----+---------+
|2022|   A1|   cat| eng|    3|56.768639|
|2022|   A1|rabbit| eng|   10|56.768639|
|2022|   A2|   dog| eng|   10|54.114841|
|2022|   A2| mouse| eng|   20|81.114841|
+----+-----+------+----+-----+---------+
```

I want to create a  `lst` column in which an array of dictionaries:

```
+----+-----+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|data|group|lang|lst                                                                                               |
+----+-----+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2022|A1   |eng |[{count : 3, value : 56.768639, word : cat}, {count : 10, value : 56.768639, word :rabbit}]|
|2022|A2   |eng |[{count : 10, value : 54.114841, word : dog}, {count : 20, value : 81.114841, word : mouse}]|
```

I tried this:

```
map_values = df\
    .groupBy('data', 'group', 'lang')\
    .agg(F.collect_list(F.create_map(F.col('word'), F.col('count'), F.col('value'))).alias('descr'))
```

But it gives me an error

```
cannot resolve 'map(`word`, `count`, `value`)' due to data type mismatch: map expects a positive even number of arguments.;
```

Comment: `to_json` will make a "String" JSON.  If you want to use `create_map` which will retain as JSON "object".  The error is saying that `create_map` requires, needs even number of arguments because it requires `creaate_map(F.lit('key_name'), F.col('value_col'), F.lit('key2_name'), F.col('value2_col'),...)`.   Other option is You may be able to use `struct` depends on what you do with the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use `to_json` function to generate json string, then use `collect_list` function to aggregate.

```
map_values = df\
    .groupBy('data', 'group', 'lang')\
    .agg(F.collect_list(F.to_json(F.struct(F.col('count'), F.col('value'), F.col('word')))).alias('descr'))
```